# Configuring delimiter for Hive MR Jobs

Tags: hive

Is there any way to configure the delimiter for Hive MR Jobs??
The default delimiter being used by hive internally is "hive delimiter" (/001). My usecase is to configure the delimiter so that i can use any delimiter as per the requirement. In hadoop there is a property "mapred.textoutputformatter.separator" which will set the key-value separator to the value specified for this property..Is there any such way to configure the delimiter in Hive?..I searched many but didn't get any useful links. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As of hive-0.11.0, you can write

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '...'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
SELECT ...
```

See [HIVE-3682](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3682) for the complete syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
SELECT (rest of your query)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'YourChar' (example: FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t')
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But the issue here is that, we are writing the hive MR o/p to a dfs location. If hive is using the delimiter as '\001', then there might be some way to configure it explicitly, like by setting some properties,..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :-

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim'='-','serialization.format'='-')
```

This will separate columns using - *delimiter* but it is specific to **LazSimpleSerde**.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY option to write to a hdfs file.
If you create a hive table on top of the hdfs file with no delimiter, it will take '\001' as delimiter, so you can read the file from a hive table without any issues

Answer (score 0):

If you source table dnt not specify the delimiter in the create schema statement, then you wont be able to change that. You op will always contain the default. And yes the delimiter will be controlled by create schema for the source table. So that isnt configurable either. 
I have had a similar issue and ended up modifying 001 as second step after finishing hive MR job.